# "offen stehen gelassen" getrennt oder zusammen

Tags: compound, separable-verb, separable

Es gibt sowohl "offenstehen" als auch "stehenlassen" als eigene Verben.  Sollte die Phrase **"offen stehen gelassen"** (z. B. in "Ich habe die Tür offen stehen gelassen.") demnach irgendwie (teilweise) zusammengeschrieben werden?

Mir scheint in dieser Kombination nur die Version mit drei Wörtern richtig auszusehen.  Allerdings habe ich keine gute Begründung.  Ich suche also nach einer Antwort und einer Begründung.

Comment: Übrigens ist "*ge*lassen" wahrscheinlich in den meisten Fällen falsch - Hier muss ein **Ersatzinfinitiv** zum Einsatz kommen, es heisst also richtig "offen stehen lassen"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL/DR: zusammenschreiben als *offenstehen (ge)lassen*.

---

Das ändert die Bedeutung:

> Ich habe die Tür offenstehen (ge)lassen.

*offenstehen* würde ich definieren als "Ungeschlossensein eines fest verbundenen Öffnungsmechanismus (Tür, Deckel, o.ä)".  *Lassen* ist aber das Hauptverb des Satzes, welches einen Infinitv als Argument nimmt.  (Beim *ge-* bin ich mir nicht mal sicher, aber es klingt natürlicher ohne.)

Im Gegensatz dazu:

> Ich habe das Marmeladeglas offen stehengelassen.

oder

> Ich habe das Marmeladeglas offen stehen gelassen.

Hier geht es um *stehenlassen*, das einfach mit einem Adverb modifiziert wird. *Stehenlassen* ist ein trennbares Verb, also kann man es sicher nach irgendeiner Rechtschreibversion auch so getrennt schreiben.

Wenn man jetzt schreiben würde,

> Ich habe die Tür offen stehen gelassen.

hieße das somit, dass du die Tür *stehengelassen* hast -- und zwar zufällig offen.  Das kann einen Sachverhalt beschreiben, bei dem du sie ausgehängt und neu lackiert hast, aber nicht, dass du sie (im eingehängten Zustand) nicht verschlossen hast.

Comment: Danke!  Das mit dem Entfallen des `ge-` vor dem `lassen` ist sehr interessant.  Ich habe gerade bemerkt, dass meine eigentliche Formulierung aber tatsächlich im Perfekt steht (»eine Tür, die offen stehen gelassen worden ist«); mein Beispiel war also leider nicht ganz korrekt.  Würdest du da auch für ein »eine Tür, die offenstehen gelassen worden ist« plädieren?

Comment: Das ist Passiv, im Perfekt war der Satz eh schon :P Aber ja, genau so würde ich das schreiben. Zum _ge-_: der Ersatzinfiniv (ohne _ge-_) wird eigentlich bei Modalverben gebraucht -- und _lassen_ ist nahe dran an einem Modalverb, wenn auch kein echtes. Allerdings haben Modalverben kein Passiv, weswegen im Passivsatz mit _lassen_ das _ge-_ IMO obligatorisch ist.

Comment: Wobei die Verwendung des Ersatzinfinitivs umgangssprachlich entweder nicht konsistent oder zumindest freier ist.